# MacBook Pro Hang

Tags: macbook-pro, performance

I bought a new MacBook Pro with a Core i5 processor; everything is very good but it hangs a lot. I changed its hard drive and used Apple's diagnostic test but neither helped.

Any ideas about what could be the problem?

Comment: Do you still have the problem if you put back the original hard drive?

Answer (score 5):

It’s a new machine, if it hangs “out of the box” take it back for repairs, it’s under warranty. It could be the memory (RAM). Don’t change anything, let the Apple folks do it for you.